# GitHub Action in swift workspace

Tags: swift, xcodebuild, github-actions, xcode-workspace

I am trying to use Github Actions to run an `xcodebuild` command on my `xcworkspace`.
However, any configuration fails with the error `Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier: { platform: iOS Simulator, OS: latest, name:iPhone 11 Pro }`

Here is my `swift.yml` file

```
name: Unit Tests
on: [push]
jobs:
  test:

  runs-on: macOS-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: List Simulators
  run: xcrun instruments -s
- name: Run tests
  run: xcodebuild test -workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyScheme" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro,OS=latest"
```

As you can see, I am also logging all available devices on the CI machine. This clearly shows me several iPhone 11 Pro (Max).

Things I already tried:

- use specific OS version
- lower build target
- force Xcode version to 11.3
- grep ID of a simulator from the above-mentioned list and use that instead of the name parameter
- boot simulators before running tests

Am I missing anything obvious?

Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Force Xcode version to `Xcode 11.3` and `clean test`

```
name: Unit Tests
on: [push]
jobs:
  test:

  runs-on: macOS-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Force Xcode 11
  run: sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_11.3.app
- name: List Simulators
  run: xcrun instruments -s
- name: Run tests
  run: xcodebuild clean test -workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace' -scheme 'MyScheme' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11 Pro Max,OS=latest'
```

Comment: Tried that. Error Message is "Scheme is not configured for action clean" (don't quote me on that, will look at the exact message later again) and if I remove clean it falls back to the previous error message